# function php to Plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have php code it's for reading excel file (.xlsx) and i want to make plugin for Wordpress ( just a simple plugin ). tested on localhost Wordpress it's work perfectly, but when i uploaded to my site it's not work. when i click submit button just appear blank page.

```
<form method="post" action="">
Number : <input type="text" name"number" /> </br>
<input type"submit">
</form>




function find(){

    if (isset($_POST['number']) {
    $number = $_POST["number"];

    require_once ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'includes\classes\PHPExcel.php');
    $tmpfname = ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'number.xlsx');
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $excel_arr = $worksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);

        for ($row=1;$row <=$lastRow;$row++){

             if ($excel_arr[$row]["A"] == $number ) {
               echo $excel_arr[$row]["A"];
               break;
             }
        }
   }
}

add_shortcode('show_number', 'find');
```

Comment: The form needs to live inside the shortcode, otherwise there's no reason for the form to display.  I'm curious how you got it to display in the first place - how are you accessing / including / referencing this code?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/201650/how-to-add-and-submit-input-fields-using-a-shortcode

Comment: already  place The form to inside the shortcode but still doesn't work, please see my explanation, i have edited.

I do not know, I just see on youtube. I do not really understand about php, I just learned: D

Comment: Hi Irfan - so, you are asking a new question, but within this old / existing question.  If the original issue is resolved, then please _upvote and / or accept_ an answer that helped you.  Then, if you're now having problems with the  Excel doc getting read / outputted, ask a _new question_ about that.

Comment: Hi Cale, no, my problem is same, not new question
Before I think the implementation of code to read excel and then made a plugin for wordpress, the problem is not about the form, btw thanks Cale: D

Comment: No, it is not.  The question is very different.  It may be the same code for you, but the question is now different.  We helped you fix the original problem, and now you've got a new problem with the same shortcode.  Please ask a new question.

Comment: Oh ok i apologize
i will ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

Insert HTML form code inside "find()" function. So form show with shortcode "show_number" and and get result.

Comment: Already done but still load blank page, I think I'm wrong in writing function to read Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function find(){

    if (isset($_POST['number']) {
    $number = $_POST["number"];

    require_once ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'includes\classes\PHPExcel.php');
    $tmpfname = ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'number.xlsx');
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $excel_arr = $worksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);

        for ($row=1;$row <=$lastRow;$row++){

             if ($excel_arr[$row]["A"] == $number ) {
               echo $excel_arr[$row]["A"];
               break;
             }
        }
   }
   ?>
   <form method="post" action="">
    Number : <input type="text" name"number" /> </br>
    <input type"submit">
    </form>
   <?php
}

add_shortcode('show_number', 'find');
?>
```